# how can we use for each loops for string array to print only non empty elements

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

I want for each to go through all elements of a string array and print only all non-empty element

```java
    String[] arr = {"one","  two"," "," four"};
    for (String x:arr) {
        boolean i = x.startsWith(" ");
            if (i==false) {
                System.out.println(x);
         }
     }
```

I need output as:

```
one 
two
four
```

Comment: Use String.trim()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startsWith(" ")` will only match strings that start with an empty space. The issues with this is that you will miss strings that don't have any spaces (e.g. ""), and you will ignore strings that aren't empty but start with an empty space (e.g. " five").

You should first use `trim()` to remove any extra space, and then use the method `isEmpty()` to check if the string is completely empty.

```
if (!x.trim().isEmpty()) { // assuming x is never null
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help

```
        Arrays.stream(arr).filter(s -> !s.trim().isEmpty()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

check if string is empty after trim()

```
for(String x:arr){
 if(!x.trim().isEmtpty()){
   System.out.println(x);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First trim all the leading or trailing whitespaces then check if string is empty or not as below:
The java string `trim()` method eliminates leading and trailing spaces.
For example, for string str =   `five` , the `str.trim()` will return `five` after removing the leading and trailing whitespace.
And `isEmpty()` will check if string is empty.

```java
String[] arr = {"one","two"," ","four"};
    for (String x : arr) {
        boolean empty = x.trim().isEmpty();
            if ( !empty ) {
                System.out.println(x);
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String#isBlank, provided you have java 11 or higher. Some approaches you may modify to your needs:

```
String[] arr = {"one","  two"," "," four"};
for (String x:arr) {
     if (!x.isBlank()) {
        System.out.println(x);
     }
 }
```

or converting your array to list

```
String[] arr = {"one","  two"," "," four"};

Arrays.asList(arr).forEach(str -> {
    if(!str.isBlank()){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
});
```

Or using streams and filtering the blank ones

```
String[] arr = {"one","  two"," "," four"};
Arrays.stream(arr)
      .filter(Predicate.not(String::isBlank))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```